# How do you match military time?

Tags: java, regex

I'm trying to create a valid Java regex for matching strings representing standard "military time":

```
String militaryTimeRegex = "^([01]\d|2[0-3]):?([0-5]\d)$";
```

This gives me a compiler error:

> Invalid escape sequence (valid ones are  \b  \t  \n  \f  \r  \"  \'  \ )

Where am I going wrong?!?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Google_(verb)

Comment: @DirtyMikeAndTheBoys it means: go search in http://www.google.com the error

Comment: If only SO allowed lmgtfy as a response.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make sure you use double backslashes for escaping characters:

```
String militaryTimeRegex = "^([01]\\d|2[0-3]):?([0-5]\\d)$";
```

Single backslashes indicate the beginning of an escape sequence. You need to use `\\` to get the character as it appears in the `String`.

---

To answer your comment, you are currently only matching `19:00`. You need to account for the additional `:00` at the end of the `String` in your pattern:

```
String militaryTimeRegex = "^([01]\\d|2[0-3]):?([0-5]\\d):?([0-5]\\d)$";
```

Comment: Thanks @Reimeus - but when I execute `boolean b = "19:00:00".matches(militaryTimeRegex)`, I get `false`. There's still something going on here...thanks again! (+1)

Comment: Yep, just repeat your last matching group and you're sorted

Answer (score 3):

In Java, you need to double-escape all the `\` characters:

```
String militaryTimeRegex = "^([01]\\d|2[0-3]):([0-5]\\d):([0-5]\\d)$";
```

Why? because `\` is the escape character for strings, and if you need a literal `\` to appear somewhere inside a string, then you have to escape it, too: `\\`.

Comment: Thanks @Oscar Lopez. (+1) - please see my comment under Reimeus' answer - I have the same question for you!

Comment: @DirtyMikeAndTheBoys I fixed the regular expression, see my updated answer

Answer (score 2):

According to the error message `\d` does not exist. Escape it with `\\d`

Comment: Thanks @user000001 (+1) - please see my comment under Reimeus' answe - I have the same question for you!

Answer (score 2):

Although `\d` is valid regex syntax, you need to escape the backslash in the Java string:

```
String militaryTimeRegex = "^([01]\\d|2[0-3]):?([0-5]\\d)$";
```

Comment: Thanks @F.J. (+1) - please see my comment under Reimeus' answe - I have the same question for you!